# Why am I getting this redefinition of class error?

Tags: c++, class, redefinition

Apologies for the code dump:

gameObject.cpp:

```
#include "gameObject.h"
class gameObject
{
    private:
    int x;
    int y;
    public:
    gameObject()
    {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    }

    gameObject(int inx, int iny)
    {
        x = inx;
        y = iny;
    }

    ~gameObject()
    {
    //
    }
    int add()
    {
        return x+y;
    }
};
```

gameObject.h:

```
class gameObject
{
    private:
    int x;
    int y;
    public:
    gameObject();

    gameObject(int inx, int iny);
    ~gameObject();
    int add();
};
```

Errors:

```
||=== terrac, Debug ===|
C:\terrac\gameObject.cpp|4|error: redefinition of `class gameObject'|
C:\terrac\gameObject.h|3|error: previous definition of `class gameObject'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Help?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're defining the class in the header file, include the header file into a *.cpp file and define the class a second time because the first definition is dragged into the translation unit by the header file. But only one gameObject class definition is allowed per translation unit.

You actually don't need to define the class a second time just to implement the functions. Implement the functions like this:

```
#include "gameObject.h"

gameObject::gameObject(int inx, int iny)
{
    x = inx;
    y = iny;
}

int gameObject::add()
{
    return x+y;
}
```

etc

Answer (score 25):

add in header files

```html
#pragma once
```

Comment: What will this achieve?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `#pragma once` achieves the same thing as [zhangxiang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37145587/10001361)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you need to ```include``` two separate files, while those two ```include``` the same third file, then your compiler will give you an error because it will try to include the same file twice, using ```#pragma once``` stops the compiler from behaving like this, by simply not allowing it to ```include``` the same file twice, and use the once included file both times.

Answer (score 10):

the implementation in the cpp file should be in the form

```
gameObject::gameObject()
    {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    }
gameObject::gameObject(int inx, int iny)
    {
        x = inx;
        y = iny;
    }

gameObject::~gameObject()
    {
    //
    }
int gameObject::add()
    {
        return x+y;
    }
```

not within a 
class gameObject
{
}
definition block

Comment: In addition to this fix, constructors should use *ctor-initializer-list* and not the body of the constructor to initialize member variables.

Comment: absolutely agree (though not related to the question)(+1 from me)

Answer (score 10):

You should wrap the `.h` file like so:

```
#ifndef Included_NameModel_H

#define Included_NameModel_H

// Existing code goes here

#endif
```

Comment: Also you can ignore .h files, and place everything inside a .cpp file, with that #ifndef command.

Answer (score 5):

You're defining the same class twice is why.

If your intent is to implement the methods in the CPP file then do so something like this:

```
gameObject::gameObject()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
gameObject::~gameObject()
{
    //
}
int gameObject::add()
{
        return x+y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are having issues with templates or you are calling the class from another .cpp file

try using '#pragma once' in your header file.

Comment: This was already posted as an answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873122/3367799).

Answer (score 2):

Either try adding `#pragma once` at the top of your file, or the old way... Place this at the top of your code

```
#ifndef GAME_H //ensuring that this object is only initialized once
#define GAME_H
```

and this below the last line

```
#endif
```

Which will ensure only a single initialization of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Include a few #ifndef name #define name #endif preprocessor that should solve your problem.
The issue is it going from the header to the function then back to the header so it is redefining the class with all the preprocessor(#include) multiple times.

Answer (score -2):

You define the `class gameObject` in both your `.cpp` file and your `.h` file.
That is creating a redefinition error.

You should define the class, **ONCE**, in **ONE** place.
(convention says the definition is in the `.h`, and all the implementation is in the `.cpp`)

Please help us understand better, what part of the error message did you have trouble with?

The first part of the error says the class has been redefined in `gameObject.cpp`
The second part of the error says the previous definition is in `gameObject.h`.

How much clearer could the message be?

Comment: It may be clear to you, but it is probably not clear to newbies